# css to sass конвертация

Tags: css, sass

Как сконвертировать css (7965 строк) в sass?

Программы из серии коала, компас и дригие я знаю но она конвертирует наоборот sass в css. 
Конвертаторы он-лайн (http://sebastianpontow.de/css2compass/) конвертируют такой файл с кучей ошибок.

Из этого вопрос: реально ли это вообще, или это просто мечты? Если реально, то как?

Comment: А вам с какой целью? Надо собрать именно тот Sass, из которого было сгенерировано, или любой, который Sass может скомпилировать, получив то же самое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмём, к примеру, строку "Привет мир!", как результат программы. Её можно получить очень большим количеством способов, например:

```
1. print "Hello world!";
2. my $string = "Hello world!"; print $string;
3. my $a = "Hello"; my $b = " World!"; print $a . $b;
4. ...
```

Так же и с css правилами. На sass одно css правило тоже можно получить кучей разных способов. А когда же взаимосвязанных правил больше чем два (напр. ~8000 строк как в вопросе), то без ИИ, которое написало бы sass код должного качества, тут, по-моему мнению, вряд ли обойтись. Так что, скорее всего, это мечты.